# How could I format title which includes a date using gawk and sed?

Tags: bash, date, sed, title, gawk

I have gawk at my disposal and I have the following text I wish to format:

```
Trip.to.Washington.2004.08...
Florida.1993.12...
Aunt.Rose.2011.06...
```

I would like it to appear as follows:

```
Trip to Washington (2004)
Florida (1993)
Aunt Rose (2011)
```

The number of words in the title varies as does the amount of words following the year. The separator is sometimes a white space rather than a period.

Edit:

I was able achieve the desired output using:

```
echo Trip.to.Washington.2004.08... |
sed -n 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/p' |
gawk 'BEGIN { FS="." } { print $1" "$2" "$3" ("$NF")" }'
```

Which returns:

```
Trip to Washington (2004)
```

The problem is that this will fail if there are more, or less, words in the title. It will also fail if the words are separated by anything other than a period.

I also found it is possible to return every field except for the last field using:

```
awk '{$NF=""; print $0}' file
```

Unfortunately, my experience with gawk is very limited. I haven't a clue as to how to correctly make use of this statement within my existing gawk.

Comment: Edited my post to include my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/(\1)/; s/\./ /g' foo
Trip to Washington (2004)
Florida (1993)
Aunt Rose (2011)
```

Explained:

- first surround 4 digit numbers and everything following them with parentheses using back-referencing :`s/\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/(\1)/;`
- then replace all periods with space `s/\./ /g`

Answer (score 0):

You an easily perform the substitution in Awk as well.  If the words you want to replace are always the last five tokens on the dot-separated line, you could do something like

```
echo "Trip.to.Washington.2004.08..." |
gawk -F . '{ for(i=1; i<=NF-5; ++i) printf "%s ", $i; print "(" $NF-4 ")" }'
```

We loop over the tokens up to five less than `NF` and print each followed by a space.  Then, we print the next one which is still left inside a pair of parentheses, and never print the rest.

So when `i` is 1, we print `$1`, which in this case is `Trip`, followed by a space.

When `i` is 2, we print `$2`, which in this case is `to`, again followed by a space.

When we reach `Washington` the loop ends because this is the fifth field counting from the end.  We print that followed by a space, too, then exit the loop.

Then we still print the fourth from the end surrounded by parentheses, which should get us the year.

The `-F .` is a shorthand for your `BEGIN { FS="." }` but I made this change just for brevity; either way works fine.

There is nothing `gawk` specific here so you could use the generic `awk` as well.

Comment: If the final two dots in your example are just placeholders for digits, the offsets will change, of course.  Try with `NF-3` for the `for` loop and `NF-2` for the year in parentheses if your actual file names are like `Trip.to.Washington.2004.08.23-25` rather than what you show in your question.